# Swift 2 Beacon scan in background

Tags: ios, swift2, ibeacon

I'm trying to run a beacon background detection in my app.
I created a dedicated class for this and launch it in my ViewController:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      beaconSharedInstance
      ....
    }
```

and here is the code of my class:

```
let beaconSharedInstance = iBeacon();

class iBeacon: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
var beaconRegion:CLBeaconRegion!

override init(){

    super.init()

    let uuidString = "FDA50693-A4E2-4FB1-AFCF-C6EB07640978"
    let beaconIdentifier = "uby-06B524"
    let beaconUUID:NSUUID = NSUUID(UUIDString: uuidString)!
    beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: beaconUUID, identifier: beaconIdentifier)

    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self

    if(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedAlways){
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }

    locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    locationManager!.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion)
}


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager,
                     didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon],
                                     inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion)  {
    print("didRangeBeacons");

    if(beacons.count > 0) {

        print("Discovered beacon \(beacons[0].rssi) dBM name: \(beacons[0].proximityUUID)")
    }


}
```

}

this class is working perfectly in foreground, but as soon as my app is becoming inactive, I can see in the log files:

```
Ending background task
```

and the CLLocatioManager stops...

I set Location updates in the Background mode of my project as well as NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in my info.plist file but I still have the same behavior, my thread stops when app is inactive.

I also tried to launch my Thread like this:

```
let qualityOfServiceClass = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
    let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
        print("Running beacon detection in the background queue")
        beaconSharedInstance
    })
```

but in that case CLLocationManager never starts...any idea ?

Comment: Where does the "ending background task" log come from?  Are you using `beginBackgroundTaskWithExoirariinHandler`?

Answer (score 0):

The background task needs to have a loop, otherwise it will simply exit.  Try:

```
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
    print("Running beacon detection in the background queue")
    beaconSharedInstance
    while(true) {
      NSThread.sleepForTineInterval(1)
      print("running...")
    }
})
```

Comment: are you sure ? because, when my app is in foreground, scan is performed every seconds...

Comment: by adding your code, I only have running...
running...
running...
running...
running...
running...
running...
running...
running...
running...
but CLLocationManager ever starts

Comment: Right, that is good -- it means that the background task is actually running and it stays running.  Do you not see "didRangeBeacons"?  If not, that may suggest no beacons are in the vicinity.  One other thought:  it is possible the init sequence is a problem.  Try moving `let beaconSharedInstance = iBeacon();`  just before the while(true), and wee what happens.

Comment: no, I cannot see didRangeBeacons when I launch beaconSharedInstance as an independent Thread, it seems the didRangeBeacons is never called if it is not in the main Thread....even if there is no beacon in range, this function is called (in the main Thread).

Comment: btw when I set my app inactive/background (lock the screen for instance), I have in my logs "Ending background task"